# Restaurar Script de Base de Datos

Tags: sql-server, script

Tengo un script de una base de datos que generé desde SQL Server 2019, el cual al generarlo pesa casi 3GB, y al intentar restaurarlo en SQL Server 2012, me dice algo tipo que hay una excepción de memoria, es decir, que no acepta abrir archivos grandes. He investigado un poco y la respuesta es restaurarlo con comandos (sqlcmd), pero los comandos que hay usan un usuario y contraseña, lo cual yo no tengo porque lo tengo con autenticación de Windows. ¿Alguien sabe cómo le puedo hacer?

Comment: Por defecto sqlCmd usa como autenticación windows. `-E`, [sqlcmd authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-use-utility?view=sql-server-ver16). Además también puedes usar el comando `runas` para ejecutarlo como otro usuario [sqlcmd login windows](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/02febadd-3a81-4544-814c-ede23dd1220a/login-as-windows-authentication-using-sqlcmd?forum=transactsql)

Comment: ¿Por qué estás restaurando a la versión 2012? Es importante migrar a versiones más actuales y que aun reciben soporte de Microsoft. Si es para un ambiente de desarrollo o pruebas, puedes usar la edición Developer de forma gratuita.

Comment: Intento restaurar a la versión 2012 ya que las características de ese equipo no me permite instalar una versión más reciente